# How to write a list to a file in python

Tags: python, list

I have a program that encrypts the contents of a file into cipher text. I want the program to write the ciphertext, that Is in a list, to a file.

The part of my code I need help with is:

```
for char in encryptFile:
    cipherTextList = []
    if char == (" "):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    else:
        cipherText = (ord(char)) + offsetFactor
    if cipherText > 126:
        cipherText = cipherText - 94
        cipherText = (chr(cipherText))
        cipherTextList.append(cipherText)
        for cipherText in cipherTextList:
                print (cipherText,end=" ")
    with open ("newCipherFile.txt","w") as cFile:
        cFile.writelines(cipherTextList)
```

The whole program runs smoothly, however the file that is called "newCipherFile.txt" only has one character in it.

I think this has something to do with the location of the empty list "cipherTextList = []", however I have tried moving this list out of the for loop, into the function, but when I print it the part that prints the ciphertext is in an infinite loop and prints the normal text over and over again.

Any help would be lovely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

You keep overwriting opening the file with `w` so you only ever see the very last values, use `a` to append:

```
 with open("newCipherFile.txt","a") as cFile:
```

Or a better idea so to open it outside the loop once:

```
with open("newCipherFile.txt","w") as cFile:
    for char in encryptFile:
        cipherTextList = []
        ............
```

Comment: @iTzAlexF,  no worries, the second is a better option as you don't repeatedly open the file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `("newCipherFile.txt","a")` instead of `("newCipherFile.txt","w")`. `a` is for append and `w` is for over-write.